# C# GeckoWebBrowser v45 - set focus element on WebPage

Tags: c#, geckofx

I have a big problem and  i need solution
I have html code on the web page:

`<input class="fPersonalInput" name="email" id="email" value="" data-value="adres e-mail" maxlength="33" type="text">`

I don't know how to set focus on this element

Any help is much appreciated........Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `selenium.FindElement(by.XPath("xpath"))`

To get the xpath of the element use the developer tool of chrome and do right-click in the element Copy>Copy XPath

[image]

Comment: The question is about geckofx, not selenium web driver (which I suppose your answer covers)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to:

1) Get the element reference

2) Call Focus() method

```
(Browser.Document.GetElementById("email") as GeckoHtmlElement).Focus();
```

However, if you need to set the focus in order to set its value, be sure not to use any 'SendKeys()' method or similar, but rather just set the value like that:

```
(Browser.Document.GetElementById("email") as GeckoInputElement).Value = "busy@the.moment";
```